# Getting a Segmentation Fault on executing a query with a PDO instance

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, segmentation-fault

When using a PDO instance to execute a query, the script produces a segmentation fault. This occurs after verifying that the PDO object is indeed an instance of the PDO class:

```php
var_dump($db)
```

Which resulted in:

```
Object(PDO)#16 {
}
```

It would also successfully execute a query without a segmentation fault immediately after instantiating the object, but not later in the script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem ended up being a quirk of PHP's objects, and a developer that was trying to be too clever.

In PHP, objects are passed by reference (sort of) into all scopes. This means that a child scope can alter the object in the parent scope. To avoid this, the program I was working in stored the objects in a value store, and this value store would **CLONE** the variable before returning it if it was an object:

```php
    public function getConfig(string $key)
    {
        if ($this->hasConfig($key) === true) {
            if (is_object($this->configValues[$key]) === true) {
                return clone $this->configValues[$key];
            } else {
                return $this->configValues[$key];
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The `clone` keyword (detailed [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php)) creates a **shallow copy** of the object and its properties, while maintaining all properties that are references.

When a PDO object is cloned however, it does not maintain the stream handler that allows it to connect to the database, however it *does* maintain the reference.

Unfortunately, this causes a segmentation fault.

I suspect this is because internally either memory out of range (protected) is being accessed, or because the library which actually allows PHP to talk to MySQL/databases with PDO doesn't allow the stream handler to be passed in this way.

Regardless of the causes, if you clone a PDO object and then use it to query, it will cause a segmentation fault that doesn't produce errors or exceptions allowing you to debug the problem.

The actual database object must always be passed and used.

I've created this question and answer to record this particular quirk, as I wasn't able to find any reference to this particular behavior on Google when I was originally trying to debug the issue.

This behavior was observed in PHP 7.2.16, and I have not verified if it will produce similar behavior in other versions of PHP.

The expected behavior, if the stream handler cannot be safely cloned in this way, is for the `clone` keyword to throw an exception when used on a PDO object.

EDIT:

Another factor which may contribute (again, this isn't something I tested extensively) is that this particular connection uses the `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA` attribute to set an SSL cert .pem file.

Comment: These `=== true` tests are overly specific. `hasConfig` and `is_object` are intended to return a logically true/false value, there's no need for such a test. It's like `if ((($x === $y) === true) === true)`

Comment: I am well aware. The hasConfig() method is actually defined `public function hasConfig(string $key): bool`. However, I get chewed out by my less experienced colleagues in code review if I am not overly specific like this. It is unrelated to the problem I'm describing.

Comment: If your colleagues don't know what `if` does, that's very concerning, like that's covered in the first ten minutes of using PHP. If this is an artifact of your peculiar situation and just clutters up the code here and promotes bad habits. If you're going through the trouble of declaring this `public`, surely you've got a handle on how booleans work. The real trouble with `=== true` is sometimes things return *truthful* but not literally `true` responses.

Comment: No, they understand what `if` does, but they have `===` as a convention to ensure even more strict type safety throughout the programs, and for readability. They instituted it before I got here as a way for at a glance know with certainty that they type safety in an if statement wasn't a bug. Again, this is pedantry that is unrelated to the question being answered here.

Comment: `$obj = unserialize(serialize($obj));` - AKA a deep clone, (by converting it to a string and back)  [Sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/710a4c9640a9de79ce9208421bb3ff1e1a84cc49)  While not "ideal" (it's sort of a hack) it does work.

Comment: None of this works anymore: unserialize-serialize, shallow clone. PDO has been locked away, sadly